# Border で上書きしても反映されない？

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl as opx
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side

wb = opx.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

side_medium = Side(border_style='medium', color='ff000000')
side_dotted = Side(border_style='dotted', color='ff000000')
side_thin = Side(border_style='thin', color='ff000000')

cl = ws.cell(2,2)
cl.border = cl.border + Border(top=side_medium, left=side_dotted, right=side_dotted, bottom=side_medium)
cl.border = cl.border + Border(left=side_thin)

wb.save(r'C:\Users\....\test.xlsx')
```

上記コードが期待通りに動きません。
１回目の"cl.border= " で、cell(2,2) の４辺はそれぞれ期待した罫線になりますが、
２回目の"cl.border= " では、左辺が thin に上書きされるはずが、dotted のままです。
２回目の上書きを期待通りに反映させるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

デバッガで動作を追ってみました。

Borderの`+`演算で、各Sideオブジェクトの値をマージする際に、
左側(`cl.border`)、右側(`Border(left=side_thin)`)の対応するSideオブジェクトを比較するのですが、
両方に`boder_style`に値が設定されている場合、左側(`cl.border`)が採用されるようです。

```
cl.border + Border(left=side_thin) # 両方オペランドのSideにsytleがある場合、左を採用
```

そのため、左右入れ替えると意図通りになります。

```
Border(left=side_thin) + cl.border
```

ただし、`cl.border`は、`StyleProxy`型になっているため、
そのまま`+`するとエラーとなりますので、`copy`して`Border`型に変換してから
`+`すると上手く行くと思います。

```
from copy import copy
# ...略...
cl.border = Border(left=side_thin) + copy(cl.border)
```